# Publishing website along with nodejs backend and mysql database

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, hosting

Ok this my sound silly but i have no clue on how to publish node.js backend for website i made. I am new at this and i know how to publish a website there are plenty of websites that offer hosting and domain for some amount of money but i don't know about backend. For example let's say i have node.js backend that reads data from MySQL database and sends it to my local-hosted website. And let's say i have nodemon package installed so i run it with nodemon and everything works fine. My question is how to publish this nodejs app along with my website and database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get a [VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/) (Virtual Private Server) with Docker, It is the best solution.

- Just copy your node folder and put it on a node docker image!
- Got html front end? Just put it on an nginx docker image.
- MySQL too, almost everything is possible with docker!

Want to learn more about docker? [Here](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3204171/what-is-docker-the-spark-for-the-container-revolution.html#:%7E:text=Docker%20is%20a%20software%20platform,in%20isolation%20from%20one%20another.)

Answer (score 0):

Look into Heroku. Easy to use, mantain and deploy. You could either deploy from GitHub repo or directly via heroku.
Look into it here [https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs]